# Android how to reliably restart the application

Tags: android

Here is how I kill the app and start it again

```
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(this, InitialActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 500, mPendingIntent);
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Some devices are apparently unable to kill the app and then start it in 500 miliseconds and the user sees a black screen.
Is there a better, more reliable way to do this?

Comment: Difficult to say unless you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve. Why do you need to kill the process? If you just want to recreate your current `Activity` could you not just use `recreate()`?

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm also using AlarmManager but I guess it takes time to fetch data from database because my app works so smoothly when I have few items in listview and takes time only when items are much more in listview so it could be a problem loading adapter or fetching items from db.

Comment: A very reliable way would be to `throw new RuntimeException("Why am I doing this to my poor users?");` inside the method that's meant to restart your app. Doubt it would take 500ms to kill it and by default, restart the process again. Not sure why you'd like to do this though.

Comment: We have a massive memory leak that no one can fix at this point so we decided to restart the app instead

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following code pretty reliably and no need to wait 500ms, also allows you to call `overridePendingTransition` in case you want some specific animation

```
   public static void restart(Activity activity) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(activity, <your main activity>.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      activity.startActivity(intent);
   }
```

Comment: This is not restarting the application though which is what the question is asking.

Comment: well, there's no need to re-start the application. That code clears the navigation stack and restarts the "main activity".

Comment: Fully agree . It's a sign of a very bad design. You should never need to do that, ever. Alas, the OP asked about how to restart the app by killing it and respawning the process.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new activity, lets call it SuicideActivity.

Inside the SuicideActivity, just call System.exit().

The JVM will stop, and the system will restart your app, but in the parent activity.
Inside SuicideActivity you might need to delay the suicide, like

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { System.exit(0); }});
}
```

Comment: runOnUiThread() is just to get the invocation delayed to *after* onCreate() has finished. Its probably not needed

Comment: J. K. did you try this?